# JavaScript for loop stops running in the middle

Tags: javascript, loops, sorting, for-loop, reduce

I'm trying to return an array of numbers in descending order (biggest in the front).

My function seems to work but just quits in the middle.

```js
let array = [1, 9, 8, 7, 2, 6, 3, 5];
let sorted = [];

function sortNumbers(array) {
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    let max = array.reduce(function(a, b) {
      console.log(`a: ${a} b: ${b}`);
      return Math.max(a, b);
    });
    let maxIdx = array.indexOf(max);
    let biggest = array.splice(maxIdx, 1);
    sorted.push(biggest);
  }
  console.log('sorted array is: ', sorted.join(''));
  //returns 9876
}

sortNumbers(array);
```

Comment: Really bad idea changing array length inside a for loop without recognizing the consequences

Comment: Others have pointed out that the index changing messes with things. Is there anything else I should be aware of?

Comment: Nothing wrong with index changing per se....just doing it inside a loop that is dependent on that length is tricky...especially when you aren't sure which end of the array you are removing from relative to where `i` is at that point

Comment: FYI don't feel bad. Many developers know this from making same mistake during learning curve days. have certainly done it myself. before sites like this were around for quick help there was lots of head banging

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you are having is being caused by `splicing` inside the loop. You change the array as you're looping through it. The quick fix is to loop through the array backwards so you set the correct length at the beginning of the loop:

```
for (var i = array.length; i > 0; i--) {
  // etc
}
```

```js
let array = [1, 9, 8, 7, 2, 6, 3, 5];

let sorted = [];

function sortNumbers(array) {
  for (var i = array.length; i > 0; i--) {

    let max = array.reduce(function(a, b) {

      console.log(`a: ${a} b: ${b}`);
      return Math.max(a, b);

    });

    let maxIdx = array.indexOf(max);
    let biggest = array.splice(maxIdx, 1);
    sorted.push(biggest);
  }

  console.log('sorted array is: ', sorted.join('')); //returns 9876

}

sortNumbers(array);
```

Comment: Thanks for letting me know the root of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by others, it's generally risky to splice the array while looping over it. Looping backwards can help avoid issues where elements are removed and the index is thrown off, skipping elements, causing logic errors or throwing out of bounds exceptions.

Having said that, it seems you're attempting selection sort; however, if you're just trying to sort the array in reverse and join, your approach can be simplified to:

```js
const array = [1, 9, 8, 7, 2, 6, 3, 5];

const sorted = array.sort((a, b) => b - a);

console.log(sorted.join(""));
```

Comment: This is definitely the cleanest version I've seen. I was attempting to do it without using the sort method, but this is the best.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you're doing this yourself?

```
console.log(array.sort(function(a, b) { return a<b ? 1 : a>b ? -1 : 0; } ))



console.log(array.sort().reverse())
```

Comment: even simpler to do `return b-a`. return value does not have to be 1 or -1...any negative number or positive number has same effect as -1 or 1

Comment: Just trying to do it without using sort, so I'm more prepared for tech interviews.

Answer (score 0):

use Underscore.Js for doing various manipulations on Arrays and Objects.

Underscore is a JavaScript library that provides a whole mess of useful functional programming helpers without extending any built-in objects

go to following the link: https://underscorejs.org/#

_.sortBy([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], function(num){ return Math.sin(num); });